# traversing through HTML tags in iMACRO

Tags: html, imacros

I am trying to extract 'href' from the code below. There are multiple classes of `_21oy` in the code.

Here is the snippet

```
<div class="_21oy">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank">www.example.com/</a>
</div>
```

I tried this `TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:_21oy EXTRACT=HREF`

But its generating **#EANF#** error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try with the help of 'XPATH':

```
TAG XPATH="//div[@class='_21oy'][1]/a" EXTRACT=HREF
```

or

```
TAG XPATH="/descendant::div[@class='_21oy'][1]/child::a" EXTRACT=HREF
```

Comment: Well, read something about 'XPATH'. I think you can find a lot of good explanations in the web resources. E.g. [this one](http://wiki.imacros.net/XPATH)

Comment: Thank you for helping :)